# Libertine and math numbers

Tags: math-mode, libertine

Linux Libertine works fine in text, but take a look at this:

[image: the "50" is in CM]

There are also issues with radicals, etc.:

[image: more weirdness]

I'm using the following packages: `libertine`, `hologo`, `rotating`, `[libertine]newtxmath`. My code is simply `$50\%$` for the first and `$\pi\sqrt[3]{a}$` for the second. And I'm not getting any errors or warnings. What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Could you please post a complete document that reproduces your bug, rather than a screenshot of the output? Thanks.

Comment: What engine are you using? `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: @egreg - xelatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to compile a document with both `libertine` and `newtxmath` in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, the `libertine` package will load the OpenType version of the font through `fontspec`.  This causes a clash with how `fontspec` and `newtxmath` define some commands.

Embarrassingly, I recommended doing this in one of my recent answers.

There are several possible workarounds.

#### Use Unicode Math in Modern Engines

If you load the `libertinus` package instead, it will load `unicode-math` and set Libertinus Math as the math font.  This includes all symbols defined by `newtxmath`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage{libertine}
  \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\else
  \usepackage{libertinus}
\fi

\usepackage{hologo, rotating}

\begin{document}

You might understand that (There is roughly a $50\%$ chance that you do).

$\pi\sqrt[3]{a}$

\end{document}
```

#### Use Legacy 8-Bit Fonts in All Engines

You would be able to pass the `[type1]` option to `libertine` and use the legacy fonts that `newtx` expects, except that this clashes with some of the other packages you use.  So the easy answer will not work for you.  Sorry.

#### Set a Fallback Legacy Font

This replaces an earlier solution I posted, which incorrectly broke some of the fonts in the package.

The incompatibility with `newtxmath` comes from the fact that it uses the legacy 7-bit OT1 encoding for some symbols, which `libertine` does not set up under XeTeX or LuaTeX.  We can, however, tell it which Type 1 font to fall back to.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage{libertine}
\substitutefont{OT1}{LinLibertine(0)}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\textsf{You might understand that}
(There is roughly a $50\%$ chance that you do).

$\Delta \pi\sqrt[3]{a}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertine sample]

#### Monkey-Patch the Math Package

You could also override the pieces of `newtxmath` that still depend on the OT1 encoding.  The great answer by @egreg explains how.

#### ETA

By request, here is how to enable punctuation ligatures such as the interrobang.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage{libertine}
\else
  \usepackage{substitutefont}
  \usepackage[defaultfeatures={ Ligatures = {Common, Discretionary} }
             ]{libertine}
  \substitutefont{OT1}{LinLibertine(0)}{LinuxLibertineT-TLF}
\fi

\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

You might understand that (There is roughly a $50\%$ chance that you do)!?

$\Delta \pi\sqrt[3]{a}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but it removes the punctuation ligatures. Then again, I don't really need them...

Comment: @merrybot You should be able to enable them. Which ligatures do you mean?

Comment: The ?? ?! !? !! have special ligatures.

Comment: @merrybot I added a version that enables those. You can get a few more ligatures, such as st, by adding `Ligatures = Historic`.

Comment: The "patch it" stuff breaks the fonts completely. Sans turns to moo and the lowercase just disappears. :(

Comment: @merrybot Okay, I found a different approach that works correctly with Biolinum.

Comment: Only now did I realize I typed "moo" AH WHY KEYBOARD :)

Comment: Where is said approach?

Comment: @merrybot Under the Set a Fallback Font heading.

Answer (score 3):

The `libertine` package doesn't set a suitable font for `operators`, which numbers and uppercase Greek math letters are drawn from.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{b}{n}
\fi

\begin{document}

There is roughly a $50\%$ chance that $\pi\sqrt[3]{a}\Delta$ is rational.

\end{document}
```

Uppercase Greek letters are not a problem, because they're dealt with by `newtxmath`.

[image]

Comment: As an alternative to `newtx` with the `libertine` option , there exists also the `libertinust1math` package (also by M. Sharpe).

Comment: @campa You might add an answer